# HTML Scrollable table vertically and horizontally

Tags: html

I thought i had originally achieved this, but the method i used wasnt correct. I separated the table head and the table data into two separate tables, each closed within a div. I then put the overflow on the outside div of each table-segment. However, this doesnt work because when i have a large number of columns, it begins to squeeze the columns together, whereas i still want them a fix width. Can anyone help? Ive omitted the event listeners in the code below.

```
<div id='HeaderTable' style='overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;width:900px;'>
    <table border='1' style='width:1900px;float:left;'>
        <thead style='text-align:left;'>
            <tr style='display:block;'>
                <th width='100' style='width:100px;'>test1</th>
                <th width='100' style='width:100px;'>test2</th>
                <th width='100' style='width:100px;'>test3</th>
                <th width='100' style='width:100px;'>test4</th>
                <th width='100' style='width:100px;'>test5</th>
                <th width='100' style='width:100px;'>test6</th>
                <th width='100' style='width:100px;'>test7</th>
                <th width='100' style='width:100px;'>test8</th>
                <th width='100' style='width:100px;'>test9</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<div id='DataTable' style='height:300px;float:left;overflow:auto;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:scroll;width:900px;>
    <table border='1' style='width:1900px;float:left;'>
        <tbody id='ClearDetails'>
            <tr id='Row0'    style='color:black;height:auto;display:block;'>
                <td style='width:100px;'>1</td>
                <td id='Row0Col0' style='width:100px;'>1625</td>
                <td id='Row0Col0' style='width:100px;'>25</td>
                <td id='Row0Col0' style='width:100px;'>25</td>
                <td id='Row0Col0' style='width:100px;'>25</td>
                <td id='Row0Col0' style='width:100px;'>25</td>
                <td id='Row0Col0' style='width:100px;'>25</td>
                <td id='Row0Col0' style='width:100px;'>25</td>
                <td id='Row0Col0' style='width:100px;'>25</td>
                <td id='Row0Col0' style='width:100px;'>25</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve overall? I get the impression that you want only one table displayed with a header that won't scroll vertically (fixed) but that will scroll horizontally in sync with the cells containing the data. Is that it?

Comment: Yes thats what im trying to do, but it appears when the text is too long it starts to distort the alignment. Any ideas how i can do this besides making the width big enough?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have to separate into two different divs:
Check out the [Pure CSS Table with Fixed Header](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html).

Second, why is the table with in one location listed as 1900, and in another set to 900?

Third, have you turned off margins and padding to make sure the blocks are actually 100px?

Finally, in IE you have to account for the width of the scrollbar, so you will need to reduce the size of each column, or increase the width of the overall table to accommodate it.

Comment: The value of 1900 is for 19x 100px columns. I found if i didnt set a width > 900, the horizontal scollbar wouldnt appear?

Comment: Well, the width should be <1900 if you know you will have 19 columns, correct?

Comment: As for your text too long dilemma mentioned in the comments, are you using any server side language? IF so, I would create a function to use substring to try and add a "-" to the middle of the word if over a certain amount of characters.